# Global AJAX Success handler that inspects JSON data

Tags: jquery

All my REST services return some common flags as part of every JSON response structure. For example, a notifications flag.  How can I cleanly setup something to hook into every ajax request made on the page to check the response payload for the presence of these flags.

I'd also like to do something similar on the request, by having something auto add certain common parameters to the URL prior to the call.

Help please!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like `.ajaxSuccess()` [<sup>doc here</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) would let you do what you want as it is a centralized method that gets called upon success for all jQuery ajax requests.  Other global ajax handlers are listed [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Comment: This seems like the right approach, but you're missing a key detail (from the linked docs): `You can get the returned ajax contents by looking at xhr.responseXML or xhr.responseHTML for xml and html respectively.`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to set up a converter:

For instance, I use one to detect my asp.net version (3.5+ returns stuff differently) for existance of the "d" property:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    {
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "jsond",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    converters:
    {
        "json jsond": function(msg) {
        return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
        }
    }
});
```

You could likewise do the same with success:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    {
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success:
    {
        "json": function(msg) {
            MyGlobalvariable = msg.hasOwnProperty('MyFlag') ? msg.MyFlag : "";
        }
    }
});
```